# Sessions Mismatch between Google analytics and BigQuery while unnesting hits and hits.product together

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

When I try to run the below query I get 15% discrepancy in data between Google analytics and BQ data:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(Sessions) AS Sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",
      date) AS DATE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId,"-",CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))) AS Sessions,
    (COUNT(DISTINCT
        CASE
          WHEN totals.bounces = 1 THEN CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))
          ELSE NULL
        END ) / COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))))*100 AS Bounce_Rate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS Transactions,
    SUM(hits.transaction.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue,
    SUM(p.productRevenue)/1000000 AS Product_Revenue,
    (COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) / COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING), CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))))*100 AS Ecommerce_Conversion_Rate,
    (SUM(hits.transaction.transactionRevenue)/1000000)/COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS Avg_Order_Value,
    SUM(hits.item.itemQuantity) / COUNT(hits.transaction.transactionId) AS Avg_Quantity,
    device.deviceCategory AS DeviceCategory,
    channelGrouping AS DefaultChannelGrouping,
    CONCAT(trafficSource.source," / ",trafficSource.medium) AS Source_Medium
  FROM
    `[Project_ID].[Dataset].ga_sessions_2019*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST(hits.product) AS p
  GROUP BY
    DATE,
    DeviceCategory,
    DefaultChannelGrouping,
    Source_Medium )
WHERE
  DATE BETWEEN "2019-11-17"
  AND "2019-11-23"
```

But when I get rid of `UNNEST(hits.product) AS p`, I get a lower level of discrepancy. I want to know how to `UNNEST` `hits` and `hits.product` data together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cross joining with the product array. If the product array is missing the cross join will result in `NULL` - effectively erasing the whole hit and sometimes a whole session (if only with one hit without product information).
You have to `LEFT JOIN` with product array to prevent deleting hits/sessions.

```sql
FROM `[Project_ID].[Dataset].ga_sessions_2019*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS h 
  LEFT JOIN  UNNEST(product) AS p
```

or the same in short

```sql
FROM `[Project_ID].[Dataset].ga_sessions_2019*` AS t, t.hits h LEFT JOIN h.product p
```